# Migrating code from Azure SDk 1.7 to Azure SDK 2.4

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We are migrating our application from 1.7 version of Client Azure SDK to Azure SDK 2.4. In this process, I update Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Since Methods and Namespace are modified, I have rework to make use of Azure SDK 2.4 and again performance when compare tableserviceentity and tableservicecontext. Since TableServicecontext works on WCF it is very flow to expose data with OData protocol.

Instead of TableServiceContext, I was asked to use TableClient, on which thing the new API works older version works on WCF but how abt new Azure SDK works on whcih protocol and architecture.

In Azure SDK .17
this.tableServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

How to convert above code in Azure SDK > 2.0

Is there any new Code sample using Azure SDK 2.4, I could not find any example or code sample for new version Azure SDK.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at the sample code at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/, see that helps

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Storage SDK v12, you can find migration guides in the Azure SDK GitHub repos for Java and .NET:

- [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/migrationGuides)
- [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/AzureStorageNetMigrationV12.md)

You'll be able to find samples in the repos as well in the following languages:

- [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/samples)
- [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples)
- [JS/TS/browser](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples)
- [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples)